# net/http the difference between server request and client request

Tags: go

When I read the source code of the Golang `net/http`  package, it always mentioned **the difference between client requests and server requests**. I want to know when these two are generally used, (of course, client requests are well understood and are widely used in websites with front-end and back-end separation architectures)

e.g.

```
    //
    // For client requests, a nil body means the request has no
    // body, such as a GET request. The HTTP Client's Transport
    // is responsible for calling the Close method.
    //
    // For server requests, the Request Body is always non-nil
    // but will return EOF immediately when no body is present.
    // The Server will close the request body. The ServeHTTP
    // Handler does not need to.
    //
    // Body must allow Read to be called concurrently with Close.
    // In particular, calling Close should unblock a Read waiting
    // for input.
    Body io.ReadCloser
```

Comment: The word "client" doesn't mean what you think it does. HTTP is a protocol between two parties, a client and a server. The request as sent by the client is the client request and the request as received by the server is the server request.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Request` using `http.NewRequest`, then set its fields, and call `Client.Do` to issue the request. In this case, the `Request.Body` is a variable the client has to set if the request has a body.

When this request is handled on the server side, a new instance of `http.Request` is created, and that is a server request. For this use, the `Body` is never nil.